# Redshift Dist Key and Sort Key in a Data Warehouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, partition

I have a Data Warehouse in Redshift. The redshift cluster is a `2 nodes ra3.xlplus (4 vCPU, 32GB Memory)` .

I have relatively smaller dimensions - The largest one has *1M records*. The fact tables would contain around *10M records*.

Based on the blogs, answers, and videos that I have checked so far, Could below be the right combination of DISTKEY and SORTKEY?

For all dimensions -
DIST STYLE - **ALL** (since the data is less)

SORT KEY - **surrogate key of the dimension**

For all fact tables -
DIST STYLE - **KEY**

DIST KEY - The most important **dim table's surrogate key** which is frequently joined in my BI queries.

SORT KEY - **Dim_Date_ID** since this is used in where clauses.

Can someone please help in confirming whether this could be the correct combination?

Reference links that I have checked -
[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html) and [This](https://hevodata.com/blog/redshift-distribution-keys/)

Thank you!

Sanket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. In general:

- Set the `DISTKEY` to the column most commonly used in `JOIN`
- Set the `SORTKEY` to the column most used in `WHERE`

If the tables are small, then `DISTKEY ALL` is fine -- it will replicate the tables between all nodes, thereby reducing cross-node data transfer.

Preferably, use the same `DISTKEY` on all tables that are JOINed. That way, the data is distributed on the same node.

Comment: John is spot on, as usual. I'd just add that when joining a dist style all dim table to a fact table it doesn't matter what the dist key is on the fact table. Every join target is local. It will matter when joining 2 tables with dist keys. So focus on the fact to fact joins when selecting the dist key.

Comment: Hey @BillWeiner -- does the latest incarnation of Redshift automatically figure out the best DISTKEY and SORTKEY these days?

Comment: Redshift does have an auto distribution mode but that is far from choosing the best dist key. It rarely chooses a key but rather all or even.  Even is equivalent to random which is a join and group by performance killer. Unless there is a fall off a log obvious dist key I haven't seen RS make a good choice. Your experience different?